# Inequality regarding the $2$ norm of the off diagonal elements of a matrix and its eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let,  $M = (m_{i,j}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and let $O(M)$ consist of the off diagonal elements of $M$, where the main diagonal element of $O(M)$ is zero. Show that for every eigenvalue $\lambda_j(M)$ there exists an element $m_{k,k}$ so that:
$$|m_{k,k} - \lambda_j(M)| \le ||O(M)||_{2}.$$

Recall that,
$$||O(M)||_{2} = ||O(M)^{*}||_{2}.$$
By the Gershgorin circle theorem, there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$|m_{k,k} - \lambda_j(M)| \le \sum_{i \ne k}|m_{k,j}|.$$
Observe that,
$$||O(M)||_{2} = ||O(M)^{*}||_{2} \ge ||O(M)^{*}e_{k}||_{2} \ge \sum_{i \ne k}|m_{k,j}|,$$
where $e_{k}$ is the $k$'th elementary vector. Thus,
$$|m_{k,k} - \lambda_j(M)| \le ||O(M)||_{2}.$$

Does my proof look good? Any mistakes? Thanks!